# how to Receive websocket data on an html page

Tags: javascript, websocket

I would like to insert values ​​from a live wind sensor on an Html page. I go for this by Node red and the node websocket.
I did the reception test using the "simple websocket client" Chrome extension and I receive my data fine.
Alas I do not master javascript too much to bring out these values ​​on my web page. I would like to display only the "wind_speed_last" data.
how to do ? thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.86.84:1880/endpoint/test");
 //socket.onopen = function(e) {
 // alert("[open] Connection etablie");
//alert("Sending to server");
//};
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
console.log (event.data);
};
socket.onclose = function(event) {
if (event.wasClean) {
alert(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`);
} else {
// par exemple : processus serveur arrêté ou réseau en panne
// event.code est généralement 1006 dans ce cas
alert('[close] Connection died');
}
};
socket.onerror = function(error) {
alert(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};
</script>
```

consolelog .

> {"data":{"did":"001D0A71121E","ts":1654941133,"conditions":[{"lsid":340707,"data_structure_type":1,"txid":1,"temp":74.5,"hum":61.9,"dew_point":60.6,"wet_bulb":64.2,"heat_index":74.9,"wind_chill":74.5,"thw_index":74.9,"thsw_index":null,"wind_speed_last":3,"wind_dir_last":314,"wind_speed_avg_last_1_min":2.93,"wind_dir_scalar_avg_last_1_min":60,"wind_speed_avg_last_2_min":2.93,"wind_dir_scalar_avg_last_2_min":62,"wind_speed_hi_last_2_min":5,"wind_dir_at_hi_speed_last_2_min":51,"wind_speed_avg_last_10_min":3.37,"wind_dir_scalar_avg_last_10_min":null,"wind_speed_hi_last_10_min":8,"wind_dir_at_hi_speed_last_10_min":92,"rain_size":2,"rain_rate_last":0,"rain_rate_hi":0,"rainfall_last_15_min":0,"rain_rate_hi_last_15_min":0,"rainfall_last_60_min":0,"rainfall_last_24_hr":0,"rain_storm":0,"rain_storm_start_at":null,"solar_rad":null,"uv_index":null,"rx_state":0,"trans_battery_flag":0,"rainfall_daily":0,"rainfall_monthly":308,"rainfall_year":943,"rain_storm_last":45,"rain_storm_last_start_at":1654667821,"rain_storm_last_end_at":1654790460},{"lsid":340706,"data_structure_type":4,"temp_in":79.1,"hum_in":45.9,"dew_point_in":56.5,"heat_index_in":78.7},{"lsid":340705,"data_structure_type":3,"bar_sea_level":30.24,"bar_trend":0.003,"bar_absolute":29.069}]},"error":null}

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create a html file with the structure you want to be shown like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <span id="data_field_id">Initial span text</span>
    // make more for each data placeholder

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you will need to update your script to select and update the data.

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
   document.getElementById("data_field_id").textContent = 'value from event'
};
```

Make sure to grab the desired field from event.data before seting it to the textContent.

This is an example on how to make a visualization, you can build it with differents html tags other than spans, but the core of selecting the element and setting the value inside the onmessage listener will be the same.

```js
// this is a sample payload that you provided
const payload = {
   "data":{
      "did":"001D0A71121E",
      "ts":1654941133,
      "conditions":[
         {
            "lsid":340707,
            "data_structure_type":1,
            "txid":1,
            "temp":74.5,
            "hum":61.9,
            "dew_point":60.6,
            "wet_bulb":64.2,
            "heat_index":74.9,
            "wind_chill":74.5,
            "thw_index":74.9,
            "thsw_index":null,
            "wind_speed_last":3,
            "wind_dir_last":314,
            "wind_speed_avg_last_1_min":2.93,
            "wind_dir_scalar_avg_last_1_min":60,
            "wind_speed_avg_last_2_min":2.93,
            "wind_dir_scalar_avg_last_2_min":62,
            "wind_speed_hi_last_2_min":5,
            "wind_dir_at_hi_speed_last_2_min":51,
            "wind_speed_avg_last_10_min":3.37,
            "wind_dir_scalar_avg_last_10_min":null,
            "wind_speed_hi_last_10_min":8,
            "wind_dir_at_hi_speed_last_10_min":92,
            "rain_size":2,
            "rain_rate_last":0,
            "rain_rate_hi":0,
            "rainfall_last_15_min":0,
            "rain_rate_hi_last_15_min":0,
            "rainfall_last_60_min":0,
            "rainfall_last_24_hr":0,
            "rain_storm":0,
            "rain_storm_start_at":null,
            "solar_rad":null,
            "uv_index":null,
            "rx_state":0,
            "trans_battery_flag":0,
            "rainfall_daily":0,
            "rainfall_monthly":308,
            "rainfall_year":943,
            "rain_storm_last":45,
            "rain_storm_last_start_at":1654667821,
            "rain_storm_last_end_at":1654790460
         },
         {
            "lsid":340706,
            "data_structure_type":4,
            "temp_in":79.1,
            "hum_in":45.9,
            "dew_point_in":56.5,
            "heat_index_in":78.7
         },
         {
            "lsid":340705,
            "data_structure_type":3,
            "bar_sea_level":30.24,
            "bar_trend":0.003,
            "bar_absolute":29.069
         }
      ]
   },
   "error":null
}

function update(){
  // This line is to simulate a new websocket payload
  payload.data.conditions[0].wind_chill = payload.data.conditions[0].wind_chill + 10

  // this is how you get the data from payload and update the view
  const wind_chill = payload.data.conditions[0].wind_chill
  document.getElementById("wind_chill").textContent = wind_chill
}

// This is just to init the simulation
function init(){
  update()
}
init()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    wind_chill: <span id="wind_chill">Initial span text</span>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <br><br>
    <button onClick='update()'>New Payload </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I already have the html body so I included the span id. but I'm not sure what ID I need to fill in. For example, the wind speed appears "wind_speed_last" but I don't know where to include it to bring it out.

Comment: Can you share the code you have? Html + Js?

Comment: Added some snippet for you to play arround

Answer (score 0):

> 

```
<code>     
 let socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.86.84:1880/endpoint/test");
 //socket.onopen = function(e) {
 // alert("[open] Connection etablie");
 //alert("Sending to server");
 //};
  socket.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log (event.data);
 };
 socket.onclose = function(event) {
 if (event.wasClean) {
 alert(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} 
 reason=${event.reason}`);
 } else {
 // par exemple : processus serveur arrêté ou réseau en panne
 // event.code est généralement 1006 dans ce cas
 alert('[close] Connection died');
 }
 };
 socket.onerror = function(error) {
 alert(`[error] ${error.message}`);
 };
 socket.onmessage = function (event) {
 document.getElementById("wind_speed_last").textContent = 'value from 
 event'
};
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long time for answer (too much work actually) :(

i solved the trouble . here's my websocket working

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.86.84:1880/endpoint/test");
//socket.onopen = function(e) {
// alert("[open] Connection etablie");
//alert("Sending to server");
//};
socket.onclose = function(event) {
if (event.wasClean) {
alert(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} 
reason=${event.reason}`);
} else {
// par exemple : processus serveur arrêté ou réseau en panne
// event.code est généralement 1006 dans ce cas
alert('[close] Connection perdue. Rafraichissez la page');
}
};
socket.onerror = function(error) {
alert(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
var data=JSON.parse(event.data) //pour transformer le retour texte en JSON

var int=new Intl.NumberFormat("fr-FR", {maximumFractionDigits: 2, 
minimumFractionDigits: 2});

var valtemp=(data["data"]["conditions"][0]["temp"]-32)*0.55;
document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML= int.format(valtemp);

var valvent=data["data"]["conditions"][0]["wind_speed_last"]*1.609;
document.getElementById("vent").innerHTML= int.format(valvent);

document.getElementById("humidite").innerHTML=data["data"]["conditions"][0] 
["hum"];

var valpress=data["data"]["conditions"][2]["bar_sea_level"]*33.8639;
document.getElementById("pression").innerHTML= int.format(valpress);

document.getElementById("pluie").innerHTML=data["data"]["conditions"][0] 
["rain_rate_last"];

console.log (data);
};
```

Comment: You have posted two answers to your own question. Why? And please indent the code.